# Присвоение значений объектам другого класса

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-xml

Допустим в классе наследуемом от `Activity` в разметке есть `ImageView` . И требуется из другого класса , этому `ImageView` присвоить изображение из ресурсов. Посредством каких методов вы это сделаете? Приведите,пожалуйста, кусочек этого кода. Если ImageView найден методом  `findViewById(...)`  , то обратившись к этому найденному объекту, через экземпляр класса , получаем Null объект, хотя в самом классе где он найден, он естественно не Null. Так как правильно обращаться к объектам другого класса. Использование сеттер метода тоже не дает результатов.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SomeClass.MyInterface {

    private ImageView mImageView;
     //SomeClass someClass;

    @Override
    public void setImage(){
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

       SomeClass someClass =  (SomeClass) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        //т.к. активити реализует интерфейс, то в класс, сеттером, передаём её
        someClass.setInterface(this);
        //теперь вызывая метод интерфейса setImage будет вызван метод в актвити.
    }
}
```

.

```
public class SomeClass extends SurfaceView {

    private MyInterface mMyInterface;

    public SomeClass(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        mMyInterface.setImage();

    }



    public interface MyInterface{
        void setImage();
    }





     public void setInterface(MyInterface myInterface){
            mMyInterface = myInterface;
        }

        //далее где-то в классе (в к-л методе) вызываем метод setImage так:
        //mMyInterface.setImage();
    }
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example.myapplicationzzz.MainActivity">


    <view
        class="example.myapplicationzzz.SomeClass"
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </view>




    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Долго ж вы мучаетесь...

Класс должен содержать интерфейс в поле своём и иметь сеттер к нему:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public interface MyInterface{
        void setImage();
    }

    private MyInterface mMyInterface;

    public void setInterface(MyInterface myInterface){
        mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }

    //далее где-то в классе (в к-л методе) вызываем метод setImage так:
    //mMyInterface.setImage();

}
```

Актвити должно реализовать интерфейс, определённый в другом классе

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{

     private ImageView mImageView;

     @Override
     public void setImage(){
         mImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
         //если надо запускать в основном потоке,
         //т.е. этот метод был вызван не из основного
         //и происходит падение из-за обращения к разметке 
         //не из основного потока, то надо делать так:

        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            //public void run(){
                //mImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            //} 
        //});
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle b){
         super.onCreate(b);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mImageView = findViewById(/*тут id из разметки*/);

         SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
         //т.к. активити реализует интерфейс, то в класс, сеттером, передаём её
         someClass.setInterface(this);
         //теперь вызывая метод интерфейса setImage будет вызван метод в актвити. 
     }
}
```

Comment: Почему нельзя просто передать `MainActivity` классу `SomeClass` и в нем вызывать `activity.setImage()`? Я считаю что ваш способ немного перегруженный.

Comment: В принципе не обязательно даже передавать все `Activity`, можно сам `ImageView`.

Comment: @MansurNashaev, ну, для этого конкретного случая - да, можно было бы упростить, но, с другой стороны, когда понадобится ещё несколько вьюх менять и логику разбивать на части то через интерфейсы получится красивее и понятнее

Comment: По некоторым причинам долго не мог вернуться к этому вопросу. Я попробовал сделать всё что вы написали, но получаю Null когда вызываю метод setImage() из интерфейса. Создал отдельный проект для того, чтобы это проверить. Сделанное прикрепил к вопросу, но получаю ту же ошибку. SomeClass у меня объявлен в xml . в общем я всё прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: Mansur Nashaev, очень хочется увидеть Ваш вариант реализации. Я пока плохо понимаю терминалогию, что значит передать MainActivity классу SomeClass ? и как передать только сам ImageView ?

Comment: @Turalllb, вы вызываете `mMyInterface.setImage();` в конструкторе, т.е. до того как вызовете `setInterface()` - естесственно что у вас `mMyInterface` `null`. Вам надо вызывать метод интерфейса не раньше чем вы его передадите вьюхе.\

Comment: да, я понял это, исправил.  Но получаю теперь такую ошибку : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Comment: Вы не из основного потока код выполняете значит.  Попробуйте обернуть в ruOnUiThread

Comment: Дело в том что полностью мой класс объявлен так  public class SomeClass extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback . И сразу же в surfaceCreated у меня создается доп. поток  и все остальные классы работают в нём. И мне нужно  передавать изображение именно из дополнительного потока. Может и можно сделать из главного, не трогая мой архитектуру, но сомневаюсь. Попробую обернуть в ruOnUiThread, но после того как завтра прочитаю , что это вообще такое) спасибо, буду разбираться дальше

Comment: Это метод активити в методе активити испольщуйте

Comment: Я разберусь позже, мне в 5 на работу вставать. Я запустил SetImage из surfaceCreated, т.е. из главного потока и всё работает, но мне нужно из дополнительного. В общем на поставленный вопрос вы ответили. Создам позже другой, если не пойму как из дополнительного вызывать. И буду рад если объясните , что предложил  Mansur Nashaev в начале комментарий.

Comment: @Turalllb, дополнил ответ с кодом для запуска в основном потоке. А Mansur Nashaev имел в виду что можно тоже самое сделать без интерфейсов, передавая вместо оного активити или даже просто ImageView. Это бы сработало, но это плохой подход, т.к. логику надо разделять и по хорошему одна вьюха не должна знать о существовании другой и напрямую с ней взаимодействовать. Если кодить не имея это в виду то код с течением времени превращается в кашу и изменение малое в одном месте ломает всё и везде да ещё и непредсказуемо. Ну и переиспользование кода становится невозможным.