# Получить bitmap из другого класса

Tags: java, android

При попытке нарисовать на канве  полученный битмап получаю : `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference`

```
class One(){
  Bitmap mbitmap;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.field);
  }
   public Bitmap GetBitmap(){
        return mbitmap;
   }
}
```

.

```
class Two(){

   Bitmap mybitmap;
   Class one = new One(); 
   public MainGamePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
       super(context, attributeSet);
       mybitmap = one.GetBitmap;
   }
}
```

Ведь то как я описал( получение объекта через геттер) должно работать? И мне следует искать проблему в другом участке кода?

Comment: Почему минус?  Везде написано,что доступ к объектам другого класса возможен через экземпляр класса, но у меня никак не получается..

Comment: Чем являются классы One и Two? По сигнатуре метода onCreate очень похоже, что оба activity/fragment. Это так?

Comment: нет один наследуется от AppCompatActivity ,а Two() от SurfaceView .  Я так понимаю такая реализация получения доступа к объекту правильна , а проблемы у меня в том , что я не в том месте это делаю?

Comment: Я сделал правки. я описал сперва просто два активити класса, думая что ошибка не может быть связано с тем от чего класса наследуются. Ведь в любом классе я должен суметь получить объект, используя экземпляр другого класса. Но выходит это не так. И в каких случаях это может не работать я не понимаю

Comment: @Turalllb Если формально, то `Bitmap` у вас создается `onCreate()`, а вы просто создаете класс не вызывая `onCreate()` - оттуда и `null`, а по сути то что вы написали это бред, потому что `onCreate()` вызывается системой, а экземпляр `Activity` нельзя создавать тупым вызовом его конструктора.

Comment: Ух я аж просветлел. Наконец то сложилась картина. Вы и товарищ  andrei_zaitcev, напомнили мне ,что создаваясь экземпляр класса не реализует жизненных циклов класса. А еще я всё время думал, что раз я уже создал этот битмап  , то почему я из другого класса не могу им воспользоваться, используя ссылку. А теперь понимаю, что через экземпляр я получаю не ссылку , а повторную реализацию класса без его жизненых циклов (Поправьте чувствую не достаточно правильно) .  А почему я не могу воспользоваться созданным уже объектом?

Comment: Если объявить статик , то я получу ссылку к единсвенному экземпляру  объекта. А как получить доступ к экземпляру битмап, из того экземпляра класса что его создал в Oncreate ?  Что запрещает это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` - метод, которые вызывается системой для создания activity. Соответственно вызывается она только системным фреймворком и не может быть задействована для создания/получения объектов в отличных от Activity классах. В данном случае простейшим вариантом будет являться передача класса One в конструкторе класса Two.

```
class One extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.field);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

}

class Two extends SurfaceView {
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public Two(One one) {
        super(one);
        bitmap = one.getBitmap();
    }

}
```

Использовать One можно, т.к. Activity наследуется от Context.

Но это не является лучшей практикой. Особенно зависимость от определённой activity и декодированием битмапа в UI потоке. Я бы посоветовал сначала достаточно овладеть Java и лишь затем переходить к изучению Android.

Comment: Это в моем случае не подойдет , так как второй класс уже достаточно разросся. Декодирование выполняется в доп.потоке, я просто не весь код приложил.  Но вы напомнили мне как java работает. Придется как то через интерфейс реализовывать как мне объясняли тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621061 , как раз для этих моих классов. Первым делом я и пробовал через интерфейс это сделать,но что то не вышло ..Сделаю еще попытку